# How to combine one root level pom to child pom?

Tags: maven, automation

Guys is that possible to combine two pom.xml files in my project one is root level pom and other is my child pom. I want to concatenate them in single pom. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Possible, but not automatically.  You will need to manually merge, removing redundancies.

Comment: i have two artifacts id, one building the apk file and other running the tests. Root pom is with tests and child pom builds the apk file. Any idea about that ?

Comment: @DineshDhiman. Yes.  The current structure makes no sense and needs to be fixed.